# How to connect Raspberry PI 3 B to two Bluetooth modules or more using Linux Commands

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm working on a project; that needs to send data from the two Arduinos using two Bluetooth Module (One using HC-06 and the other using HC-05) to Raspberry PI 3 B; so that the RPi 3 need to connect to two Bluetooths at once, Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried? ... what problem are you facing?

Comment: i can connect only one module on the default chanel, when i tried to do the same for the other Bluetooth module it gives me that is not possible to connect it and give me "Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused" as response !

Comment: you need to add a bluetooth USB dongle to your Raspberry Pi for connecting to a second bluetooth device

Answer (score 0):

This program (btferret) and library will connect to multiple Bluetooth devices simultaneously  https://github.com/petzval/btferret. Section 3.3 in the documentation covers HC-05 connections.